# How to dynamically update result on textbox_textchange in WPF?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio, calculator, onchange

I have a tax calculator, with 1 input and 2 results in textboxes. User inputs amount, result 1 will show `Result2 - Input` and result 2 will just show the calculation done in Button.Click.

How do I make it so that it auto changes the results in the 2 textboxes on every keystroke with the input Textbox? I tried to use sendkeys Enter on textbox.change but WPF doesn't have sendkeys. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than repeat all of the details of an answer I provided to another SO user I'll just put a link to it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798029/event-names-for-converting-into-mvvm-pattern/30798256#30798256).

If you were to use that logic then you could pick up the textbox's TextChanging event use that to carry out your logic and presumably update the properties to which your other text boxes are data bound thus automatically updating them as you require.

There is an assumption here on my part that you are using mvvm.  If you aren't then what you want to achieve should be pretty straightforward in the code behind so long as you have remembered to name everything.